# Convert MySQL query to Laravel (5.5) Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a problem tying to convert the following MySQL query to the Laravel (5.5) Eloquent query builder.

```
$start = '2018-01-22'; // Some random starting point for the Query

$query = "SELECT * FROM cdr c WHERE soort=3 AND con_duur > 0 AND con_duur
>= (select kortbel_seconden from queue q where q.queue_id=c.queue_id) AND `start_tijd >= '$start'";`
```

I have the following Models:

// CDR Model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class CDR extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cdr';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cdr_id';

    public function Queue()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Queue', 'queue_id', 'queue_id');
    }
}
```

// Queue Model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Queue extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'queue';

    protected $primaryKey = 'queue_id';

    public function cdr()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CDR', 'queue_id', 'queue_id');
    }
}
```

So far I have the following code in my Controller:

```
App\Models\CDR::with('queue')
    ->where('soort', '3')
    ->where('con_duur', '>', '0')
    ->where('start_tijd', '>=' , $start)
    ->where('con_duur', '>=', ' ') // this is where the sub select from the `queue` table should be : (select kortbel_seconden from queue q where q.queue_id=c.queue_id)
    ->get();
```

I’m stuck at the point of the sub select, is there a way to do this with Laravel’s Query Builder?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use DB:raw() method?
Please check Raw Expressions here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions The first example might help you.

Comment: @Kristiyan Thanks for your reply. I don't mind using a DB::raw() method. Still I don't really understand how that will work. I've been to the Laravel docs and know of DB::Raw(), but it will still be a select on a relational table. I've 'solved it' on an other query with a join(), but the the CDR table can become quite large and I don't want to eat all the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
        DB::table('cdr AS c')
            ->select("*")
            ->where('c.soort','=',3)
            ->where('c.con_duur','>',0)
            ->where('c.con_duur','>=',function($query){

                $query->select('kortbel_seconden')
                    ->from('queue AS q')
                    ->where('q.queue_id', '=', 'c.queue_id');

            })
            ->where("c.start_tijd",">=",$start)
            ->get();
```

This part of the query:

```
->where('c.con_duur','>=',function($query){

                $query->select('kortbel_seconden')
                    ->from('queue AS q')
                    ->where('q.queue_id', '=', 'c.queue_id');

            })
```

is used to achieve the below part of the query:

```
`c`.`con_duur` >= 
  (SELECT 
    kortbel_seconden 
  FROM
    queue q 
  WHERE q.queue_id = c.queue_id)
```

The above query results can be achieved by the following query as well through join:

```
 DB::table('cdr AS c')
            ->select("c.*")
            ->join('queue AS q', 'q.queue_id', '=', 'c.queue_id')
            ->where('c.soort','=',3)
            ->where('c.con_duur','>',0)
            ->where('c.con_duur','>=','q.kortbel_seconden')
            ->where("c.start_tijd",">=",$start)
            ->get();
```

For more details you can visit:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Why? Can you add some explanation to that code that shows why it could solve the problem?

Comment: ->where('c.con_duur','>=',function($query){

                $query->select('kortbel_seconden')
                    ->from('queue AS q')
                    ->where('q.queue_id', '=', 'c.queue_id');

            })

This part of the query is equivalent to


`c`.`con_duur` >= 
  (SELECT 
    `kortbel_seconden` 
  FROM
    `queue` AS `q` 
  WHERE `q`.`queue_id` = c.queue_id)

Further more you can visit official  documentation at
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Please add such explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section